# prometheus metrics which gets concourse build duration along with the build status

Tags: prometheus, concourse, concourse-pipeline

I was initially using **Influxdb** as a datasource and could able to fetch the concourse build duration metrics with build_status using the measurement "**build finished**" (FYI.. https://mockersf.github.io/docs/metrics.html)

Now I am trying to fetch similar details using **prometheus** datasource. But i couldn't able to find the suitable metrics for the same - here: https://concourse-ci.org/metrics.html#whats-emitted; I couldn't able to find any metric which gives me build_duration along with build_status.

Could someone please help me here in achieving this..!

Comment: I tried using the below query:
concourse_builds_finished{pipeline="pipeline_name",exported_job="job_name"}

But this gives me the Count of builds finished across various dimensions I guess. Not the duration of the builds.

From the code, I could see it is emitted as a histogram:
https://github.com/concourse/concourse/blob/a4c9e8ed8205218b1fdd8646f5a107a6fbbb670e/atc/metric/emitter/prometheus.go#L575
Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: current status : https://github.com/concourse/concourse/discussions/5671#discussioncomment-19747